# use ubuntu with amd sempron processor

Tags: 14.04, amd-processor

i have a machine with an AMD Sempron Processor, 4gb ram and 500gb of hard disk. i could never use ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 with an AMD processor. it gets stuck and no found. There is something i can do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the CPU in my aging entertainment center PC is a Sempron atop a Biostar motherboard.  I suspect it is older than yours, but you have not said.  I have booted that computer to several generations of Ubuntu on CDrom and installed Ubuntu versions as old as version 8.10 onto hard drives inserted into its removable IDE hard drive tray system.  About the only thing that computer won't do, unfortunately, is to boot to USB drives, which is my latest hobby, which explains why I've not used that computer much for a while.

I suspect if yours is refusing to boot to a CD/DVD the issue could well be a dirty lens.  Please try an alternate CD/DVD drive or even imaging a USB flash drive.

Comment: If you have an older computer that will only boot from CD/DVD, you can run a live PLOP Linux CD, which will provide USB drivers. Run PLOP, connect your USB device, and use PLOP to run the USB stick and it will boot. You can get it here - http://www.plop.at/en/ploplinux/